# What to show in a payment recipient / invoice from stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an application that has a recurring monthly subscription built with stripe, my client wants a section of the website where the users can view their payments / recipient.

I see that stripe sends to the users some recipient, but is a little dark to me where should I get the recipient_number, since this value is almost all the time returning null from the webservice.

So,

What information should I show?
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The charge object will include the receipt number if a receipt was sent. Stripe doesn't provide a way for you to link directly to the receipt so you may want to consider making your own receipt view in your webapp or sending your own receipts that you can render in your app.

Comment: do you know what is the best event to catch that?